# I get TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, how to fix that

Tags: numpy, math

`import numpy as np from math import * from matplotlib.pyplot import* def f(x,y) :     return np.exp(-2*x)((sqrt(3)/6)*sin(2*sqrt(3)*x)+(1/2)*cos(2*sqrt(3)*x)) dx=0.1 a=0 b=6 N= int((b-a)/dx) x=np.linspace(a,b,N+1) y=np.zeros(N+1) y[0] = 6 y[1] = y[0] for i in range (N-1):     y[i+2]=(2-4*dx)*y[i+1]+(-1+4*dx-16*dx**2)*y[i] Y2 = f(x,y) Err = abs (Y2-y) plot(x,y,'r',x,Y2,'b') show () plot(x,Err) show()`

how to fix that? i kept get TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Clean up the formatting, and show the full error.  My first guess is you are trying to use a `math` function on a numpy array.  Don't do that.

Comment: rephrase title so question will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't give code examples like that please.
I cleaned up your code and I think you can use this:

```
import numpy as np
from math import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
def f(x,y) :
    return np.exp(-2*x)*((np.sqrt(3)/6)*np.sin(2*np.sqrt(3)*x)+(1/2)*np.cos(2*np.sqrt(3)*x))
dx=0.1
a=0
b=6
N= int((b-a)/dx) 
x=np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
y=np.zeros(N+1)
y[0] = 6
y[1] = y[0]
for i in range (N-1):
    y[i+2]=(2-4*dx)*y[i+1]+(-1+4*dx-16*dx**2)*y[i]
    Y2 = f(x,y)
    Err = abs (Y2-y)
    plot(x,y,'r',x,Y2,'b')
    plot(x,Err)
```